# how to call precise argument in php function?

Tags: php, function, arguments

Consider i'm big newbe in php, so..
I made a function with some arguments who do something, and i want to call only one argument..
Here is my test:

```
   public static function test($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)
    {

   $bob1 = "thats arg1";
   $bob2 = "thats arg2";
   $bob3 = "thats arg3";

   $arg1 = echo $bob1;
   $arg2 = echo $bob2;
   $arg3 = echo $bob3;

    }
```

Now I want to call just `$arg3`, how can I call `test($arg3);`? Is it "legal" to do `test(' ' , ' ' , $arg3 )`, or is there a better practice?

Comment: You can't _call_ arguments, you call _functions_ **with** a list of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static function test($arg1='',$arg2='',$arg3='')
{
 if(!empty($arg1)){
  echo $arg1;
  }
  elseif(!empty($arg2)){
  echo $arg2;
  }
  elseif(!empty($arg3)){
  echo $arg3;
  }
  else{ echo 'no argu'; }

}
```

I think you means like echo test('','',$arg3);

Comment: dear the better way to pass array then check from index.